# wp_link_page - wrap current page element

Tags: pagination, pages, wp-link-pages

I'm trying to make something more meaningful out of the [`wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_link_pages) result:

```
$paged_page_nav = wp_link_pages( array( 'echo' => false ) );
// Now let's wrap the nav inside <li>-elements
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '<a', '<li class="'.$classes.'"><a', $paged_page_nav );
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '/a>', '/a></li>', $paged_page_nav );

// here I'd need to wrap the currently displayed page element

echo '<ul>'.$pages_page_nav.'</ul>';
```

Currently my link pages (numbered nav/pagination) displays like this:

```
<!-- assuming we display page(d) 2/5 -->
<ul>
    <li><a href="...">1</a></li>
    2 <!-- This is the currently displayed paged, wrapped in nothing -->
    <li><a href="...">3</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">4</a></li>
    <li><a href="...">5</a></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I wouldn’t use WordPress’ internal function.
We had a very similar question recently: [How to style current page number (wp_link_pages)?](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14406/how-to-style-current-page-number-wp-link-pages/14460#14460) I wrote a small but flexible function to replace `wp_link_pages()`. It is probably easier to extend this than hacking around the return value of the native function.

Comment: thanks for the link, I couldn't find anything useable myself. Using the `'wp_link_pages_args'` filter is a pretty smart move. Added the "if you build something better, make native filters available"-thought to my tool box. Thanks again, learned something today. :)

Comment: @kaiser I just tagged the other post with `wp-link-pages`. Now we have two post posts for this tag. :)

Answer (score 3):

you could try and use the 'link_before' and 'link_after' parameter to get a handle for some str_replace; in the example, i used a `<span>`:

```
$paged_page_nav = wp_link_pages( 
  array( 
    'before' =>'', 
    'after' => '', 
    'link_before' => '<span>', 
    'link_after' => '</span>', 
    'echo' => false 
  ) 
); 
// Now let's wrap the nav inside <li>-elements 
  $paged_page_nav = str_replace( '<a', '<li class="'.$classes.'"><a', $paged_page_nav ); 
  $paged_page_nav = str_replace( '</span></a>', '</a></li>', $paged_page_nav );
  $paged_page_nav = str_replace( '"><span>', '">', $paged_page_nav ); 
// here I'd need to wrap the currently displayed page element, which could even get a different class      
  $paged_page_nav = str_replace( '<span>', '<li class="'.$classes.'">', $paged_page_nav ); 
  $paged_page_nav = str_replace( '</span>', '</li>', $paged_page_nav ); 
echo '<ul>'.$paged_page_nav.'</ul>';
```

Comment: thanks @micheal, i have an another question. hoq can i grab only next page url ?