# Wordpress Blog Posts with Pagination inside a Page/Post

Tags: wp-query, pagination

Refer to the title, I'm trying to create a shortcode for Blog Post with Pagination. I'm able to show the blog post but the pagination is not working. I tried using the code below and the link to second page is www.mysite.com/postname/page/2 . But it goes back to www.mysite.com/postname/ when I click on the pagination link to second page.

```
<?php
$big = 999999999; 

    $pagination = paginate_links( array(
        'base' => str_replace( $big, '%#%', esc_url( get_pagenum_link( $big ) ) ),
        'format' => '?paged=%#%',
        'current' => max( 1, get_query_var('paged') ),
        'total' => $this->query->max_num_pages
    ) );

    $html .= $pagination;
?>
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: `$wp_query` is your issue, this is the main query object global. You should use the variable used by your custom query

Comment: Hi Pieter, I've edited the code. It should be like this. When I click on the second page, it goes back to first page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is still somewhat a mystery what you need looking at all the comments and the question content.

Here are two approaches that should work

### FOR PAGES

I have written a complete function that will paginate any (*or almost any*) query except on single post pages. It also works out of the box for static front pages. I'm not going to go into details regarding the `get_paginated_numbers()` pagination function. Everything you need to know is discussed in [my answer here](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172818/31545), so feel free to check it out. And don't forget to modify it to suit your exact needs.

Here is a basic shortcode to showcase the usage

```
add_shortcode( 'paginate_shortcode', function ()
{
    if ( get_query_var('paged') ) { 
        $current_page = get_query_var('paged'); 
    }elseif ( get_query_var('page') ) { 
        $current_page = get_query_var('page'); 
    }else{ 
        $current_page = 1; 
    }

    $q = new WP_Query( ['posts_per_page' => 1, 'paged' => $current_page] );
    return $q->posts[0]->post_title . '</br>' . get_paginated_numbers( ['query' => $q] );
});
```

You can use `[paginate_shortcode]` on any page, it will display something like this

[image]

Note that the post title changes as the links changes

### FOR SINGLE POSTS

Single posts with paginated sub queries are not really meant to be. If you are going to use your shortcode on a single post page (*which I discourage*) like for related posts, you can use the approach that I posted in [this answer](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/172900/31545). It is quite extensive, so I'm not going to repost it here. Feel free to check it out and modify as needed

Answer (score 3):

`paged` is the query var for archive pagination, and `/page/n/` is the format for archive pagination URLs. Single posts use `page` and the format is `/postname/n/`, where `n` is the page number. Your links are redirecting because they are an invalid format.

Comment: hi Milo, could you probably provide a code sample on how to fix this issue? Thanks

Comment: Single posts have pagination? I was unaware of that. What might be the possible use case?

Comment: @KCChai - the simplest solution is to use [`wp_link_pages`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages) to generate the pagination links. you can see how it works [in source](https://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/tags/4.3.1/src/wp-includes/post-template.php#L798).

Comment: @Sisir i I suppose for long posts you want split across multiple pages. If you insert the `<!--nextpage-->` quicktag and view the post in one of the core themes, you will see the pagination links they generate.

Comment: Hi Milo, using wp_link_pages doesn't seems to work. Do you have other suggestions?

Comment: Are you using it within the loop? The context of where you're trying to accomplish this is unclear.

Comment: Milo, I tried using wp_link_pages, but it just pull all pages pagination from child posts, which is not right. I would like to create pagination for the parent loop.

Comment: @KCChai - again, I can't really help you without seeing how you're trying to accomplish this.

Comment: @KCChai - perhaps you should edit your question and add The Loop code so that we know what's going on in your loop. Also it is necessary to insert <!--nextpage--> tag through 'Text' mode of the editor. So please confirm on that too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok buddy add this code to your functions.php

```
//This function is responsible for splitting posts and pages using <!--nexpage-->
function my_link_pages() {
$paged_page_nav = wp_link_pages(
            array(
            'before' => '<div class="page-navigation"><ul><li class="pages">' . esc_html__( 'Pages:', 'domain' ) . '</li>',
            'after' => '</ul></div>',
            'link_before' => '<span>',
            'link_after' => '</span>',
            'echo' => false
            )
         );

//Add "current" and "page_divide" classes to our links
//READ: http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/17421/wp-link-page-wrap-current-page-element
// Now let's wrap the nav inside <li>-elements
$current_class = 'current';
$classes = 'page_divide';
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '<a', '<li class="'. $classes .'"><a' ,$paged_page_nav );
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '</span></a>', '</a></li>', $paged_page_nav );
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '"><span>', '">', $paged_page_nav );
//Add "current" class
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '<span>', '<li class="'. $current_class .'">', $paged_page_nav );
$paged_page_nav = str_replace( '</span>', '</li>', $paged_page_nav );
echo  $paged_page_nav ;
}
```

Then call it in your single.php like so:

```
<?php my_link_pages(); ?>
```

Make sure that you add `<!--nexpage-->` on your Post Edit screen (Select Text NOT Visual)