# REQUIRED: Could not find wp_link_pages. See: wp_link_pages by Theme Checker

Tags: customization, theme-development, coding-standards

I have run my theme through WordPress theme checker to see if it can be submitted to WordPress.org. I encountered this error:

> REQUIRED: Could not find wp_link_pages. See: wp_link_pages

But this is not true. I am using a custom function `wp_my_own_link_pages()` which is a replacement for `wp_link_pages()`. It generates pagination with a compatible HTML structure for the theme.

Did I miss something required? How can I make this work?

Comment: The error is generated because you're not using the `wp_link_pages()` function in your code. The standards require that you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, this question should be asked on the Theme Reviewers mail-list, not at WPSE. If you want official answers, you should use the official communication channels.

But to answer your question in brief: Themes that implement core features/functionality are **required** to support the core implementation of those features/functionality.

Thus, the requirement to use `wp_link_pages()` is... a requirement. Note that if you need to modify the HTML markup of the generated pagination links, you can [use the arguments passed to `wp_link_pages()`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_link_pages#Default_Usage).

Functions that are filterable can have filters applied, but wholesale replacement of core functions does not conform to the Guidelines.

Answer (score -1):

It should be okay. The requirement exists to make sure page *pagination works*. If it does you are fine. Note the theme checker cannot test all requirements, even [much simpler cases](http://wordpress.org/support/topic/plugin-theme-check-globalscontent_width-not-recognized) will fall through.

That’s why there is a theme review team, where humans make the real tests. If your upload fails, ask on the mailing list [theme-reviewers](http://lists.wordpress.org/mailman/listinfo/theme-reviewers).

*Update:* As [Chip said](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/a/82083/) it is a literal requirement. Unfortunately, `wp_link_pages()` has [not enough filters](https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/14406/how-to-style-current-page-number-wp-link-pages/14460#14460) to be really useful, so you have to submit a simplified version of your theme to wordpress.org. But you can offer an advanced version on the page for your theme.

Comment: It's actually *not* okay. WPORG-hosted Themes are required to support core implementation of any features a Theme integrates. That means using core functions, rather than custom-defined functions that do the same thing.

Comment: Note: this is a known issue. There are several tickets open regarding improving `wp_link_pages()`, including [#13578](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13578), [#21002](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/21002), and [#21266](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/ticket/13578). The general philosophy of the Theme Review Team is to drive improvements back upstream into core via Trac tickets/patches, rather than facilitating ad-hoc work-arounds on a per-Theme basis.

Comment: @ChipBennett Unless these tickets are resolved theme authors should not be forced to submit a “dumbed down” version to the repository. Quite the contrary: showing what is possible and needed could help fixing the bugs.

Comment: There is nothing "dumbed down" about `wp_link_pages()`. It could be improved, for sure. But hundreds of Theme developers manage to use and style its markup just fine. Nevertheless, that's not a discussion or debate to have here. That (again) is what we have the mailing list and the Make/Themes site for.

Comment: Thanks Chip Bennett, but if I have a perfectly working function is there a simple way to make it pass by the theme checker without complicating things?

Comment: One option: provide a Theme option to use the default page links, or "fancy" (or whatever you want to call them) page links. Enhancing/building on existing functionality is perfectly acceptable.