# How to change the page break numbering?

Tags: shortcode, pagination

I am using `<!--nextpage-->` to break my posts on multiple pages. This is working fine. But I want to further change the page numbering.

If you visit [this post](http://mycitymychoice.com/fruit-9-letters/) you will note the page breaks. I want to change the first page to "Question" while the second page to "Answer"

I went through the codex on [this page](https://codex.wordpress.org/Styling_Page-Links#Changing_the_Look_of_Page-Links) any tried following code in my theme `functions.php` but it broke my site.

```
<?php wp_link_pages('before=To read this story, &after=. &next_or_number=next
&previouspagelink=you can go back to the previous page
&nextpagelink= or you can read on to the next page'); ?>
```

Could you please help to get the right code. I do not want to keep more than two pages, if this helps. And if someone can help me to get the shortcode for  it will be cherry on top of ice cream :)

Comment: It's not clear what you mean with "shortcode for it". Something like [this](http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/11578/custom-page-links-for-paginated-posts-wp-link-pages-nextpage-quicktag?rq=1)?

Comment: So this is an XY question where Y is the question above, and the original question X is "I need to make a question post with an answer how do I structure the data and template?", you should have asked about your problem rather than the attempted solution

Answer (score 3):

Put this function in you `functions.php` -

```
function the_dramatist_wp_link_pages( $args = '' ) {
    global $page, $numpages, $multipage, $more;

    $defaults = array(
        'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'Pages:' ),
        'after'            => '</p>',
        'link_before'      => '',
        'link_after'       => '',
        'next_or_number'   => 'number',
        'separator'        => ' ',
        'nextpagelink'     => __( 'Next page' ),
        'previouspagelink' => __( 'Previous page' ),
        'pagelink'         => '%',
        'echo'             => 1
    );

    $params = wp_parse_args( $args, $defaults );

    /**
     * Filters the arguments used in retrieving page links for paginated posts.
     *
     * @since 3.0.0
     *
     * @param array $params An array of arguments for page links for paginated posts.
     */
    $r = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_args', $params );

    $output = '';
    if ( $multipage ) {
        if ( 'number' == $r['next_or_number'] ) {
            $output .= $r['before'];
            for ( $i = 1; $i <= $numpages; $i++ ) {
                if ( $i % 2 == 0) {
                    $link = $r['link_before'] . str_replace( '%', 'Answer', $r['pagelink'] ) . $r['link_after'];
                } else {
                    $link = $r['link_before'] . str_replace( '%', 'Question', $r['pagelink'] ) . $r['link_after'];
                }
                if ( $i != $page || ! $more && 1 == $page ) {
                    $link = _wp_link_page( $i ) . $link . '</a>';
                }
                /**
                 * Filters the HTML output of individual page number links.
                 *
                 * @since 3.6.0
                 *
                 * @param string $link The page number HTML output.
                 * @param int    $i    Page number for paginated posts' page links.
                 */
                $link = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $link, $i );

                // Use the custom links separator beginning with the second link.
                $output .= ( 1 === $i ) ? ' ' : $r['separator'];
                $output .= $link;
            }
            $output .= $r['after'];
        } elseif ( $more ) {
            $output .= $r['before'];
            $prev = $page - 1;
            if ( $prev > 0 ) {
                $link = _wp_link_page( $prev ) . $r['link_before'] . $r['previouspagelink'] . $r['link_after'] . '</a>';

                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
                $output .= apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $link, $prev );
            }
            $next = $page + 1;
            if ( $next <= $numpages ) {
                if ( $prev ) {
                    $output .= $r['separator'];
                }
                $link = _wp_link_page( $next ) . $r['link_before'] . $r['nextpagelink'] . $r['link_after'] . '</a>';

                /** This filter is documented in wp-includes/post-template.php */
                $output .= apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages_link', $link, $next );
            }
            $output .= $r['after'];
        }
    }

    /**
     * Filters the HTML output of page links for paginated posts.
     *
     * @since 3.6.0
     *
     * @param string $output HTML output of paginated posts' page links.
     * @param array  $args   An array of arguments.
     */
    $html = apply_filters( 'wp_link_pages', $output, $args );

    if ( $r['echo'] ) {
        echo $html;
    }
    return $html;
}
```

And then go to your theme directory. Search and replace the `wp_link_pages` function names with `the_dramatist_wp_link_pages`. And it'll work as you wanted. Usually the `wp_link_pages` exists in `content-{template-name}.php`. So if you have any of those files in your theme please look at theme first. Here I've added a screenshot-[image]

And after that you do your styling. Have fun.

**The function works on odd-even basis. It considers the odd part as 'Question' and the even part as 'Answer'**

Comment: Hi @the_dramatist this is not working correctly, please check the link http://amexing.in/index.php/2016/08/17/hello-world/ i cant see both Question and Answer

Comment: @AvinashPatel, try the edited code. I think it'll do your job. :)

Comment: @AvinashPatel, if this answer helped you, then would you please accept the answer ?

Answer (score 1):

The example in the codex has faulty quotation marks. The developer area has more detail on how to use [`wp_link_pages`](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_link_pages/). Example usage:

```
<?php
$args = array(
    'before'           => '<p>' . __( 'To read this story' ),
    'after'            => '</p>',
    'link_before'      => '',
    'link_after'       => '',
    'next_or_number'   => 'next',
    'separator'        => ' ',
    'nextpagelink'     => __( 'you can go back to the previous page' ),
    'previouspagelink' => __( ' or you can read on to the next page' ),
    'pagelink'         => '%',
    'echo'             => 1
    );
wp_link_pages ($args);
?>
```

Comment: I tried this... Some how this thing has not worked. :( I don't know why. May be it was not hooked to anything.Then I tried my answer and it worked.

Comment: @the_dramatist You may have a plugin that is also messing with pagination.

Comment: Nope... I just tried your edited code. And there are two plugins installed is `WooCommerce` and `WordPress Importer`. Your code is not working. Can you please check on your system. @cjbj

Comment: I've been using this code for many years without any problems. Where in your template have you tried inserting it?

Comment: No, not in template. At `functions.php`....

Comment: Ah yes, then it won't work. `wp_link_pages` is used in template files in exactly the place where you want them to appear. Your filter in `functions.php` would alter the output of `wp_link_pages`, but you cannot change its place on the page.

Comment: Hi @cjbj i tried the code in functions.php and it didnt work. Do you have some simple code that can be placed in functions.php.

Hi the_dramatist your code is working partially. At a time i can see only one page break name either Question or Answer they both should appear all the time... You can check this page [link]http://amexing.in/index.php/2016/08/17/hello-world/ to understand what am I talking.

Comment: @AvinashPatel The code is not supposed to go in `functions.php`, but in the template file on the exact location where you want the links to appear.